# Rep statistics - per tag

Tags: support, reputation, statistics

Is there any way to get the breakdown of my rep per tag ? As there are badges available depending on how many upvotes I have per tag it makes sense to get these stats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - click the tag in question, then go to the "stats" tab and you will see the top answerers and askers, both from the top 30 days and all time, in that tag.

As Jon notes, this isn't strictly the reputation gained from those posts (due to rep caps, etc) but for users that occasionally (or never) hit the cap, it's definitely close enough.

Comment: And your stats will be at the bottom of each list, even if you aren't in the top 20 for that list.

Comment: Yes..I got it now.

Comment: What does the column of grey numbers mean?

Comment: The left column is the total number of upvotes in that tag to non-wiki posts during that time period. The right column is the number of non-wiki posts that were upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can get the *votes* on a per tag basis, but not the actual reputation gained via that tag. They're not the same thing, due to accepted answers, bounty and the reputation cap.

If you're specifically interested in how close you are to getting a badge, however, then the upvotes are what you really need to know anyway.

Comment: Note: this is only an issue if you're Jon Skeet ;-)

Comment: I have some accepted answers..but no reps from bounty questions, and certainly nowhere near hitting the reputation cap per day :-(

Answer (score 1):

Each user page now has a direct breakdown of votes per tag per user, under the "Tags" heading.

Comment: Holy shoot! Just this morning I wondered how much I had votes and rep on each tag. I couldn't believe my eyes it changed since yesterday